# Data manipulation in R with less processing time

Tags: r

How to reduce processing time to manipulate the data in below format? I have almost 100 000 data in similar format where the column may differ hence looking for generic code which can identify the no of columns and provide the output.

**My actual data looks alike:**

[image]

```
Verbatim <- c("dum1",   "dum2", "dum3", "dum4", "dum5")
Code_1 <- c("998 - NOTHING DISLIKED;nosort",    "066 - dislike/ contains sugar (unspecified)",  "138 - too expensive",  "127 - only good for kids", "138 - too expensive")
Code_2 <- c("", "051 - not calorie-free",   "111 - wasteful/ too much packaging",   "138 - too expensive",  "052 - high in carbohydrates")
Code_3 <- c("","","127 - only good for kids",   "067 - high in sugar",  "131 - not good for breakfast/ morning")    
Code_4 <- c("","","", "068 - dislike/ contains high fructose corn syrup",   "125 - not good for a snack")   
Code_5 <- c("","","","","123 - not good for kids")  
Code_6 <- c("","","","","017 - dislike taste of/ contains center/ filling/ stuffing (unspecified)")
Code_7 <- c("","","","","102 - messy")  
Code_8 <- c("","","","","106 - other ease of packaging comments;nosort")

Raw_data <- data.frame(Verbatim,Code_1,Code_2,Code_3,Code_4,Code_5,Code_6,Code_7,Code_8)
```

So with the above data we would like to spread the data in below manner wherein all the categories mentioned from Code1 to Code8 will gonna be a column header (unique values) than the respective counts will be shown against it.

[image]

```
Required_ouput <- data.frame(
  "Verbatim" <- c("dum1", "dum2","dum3","dum4", "dum5"),
  "998 - NOTHING DISLIKED;nosort" <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  "066 - dislike/ contains sugar (unspecified)" <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  "138 - too expensive" <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  "127 - only good for kids" <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  "051 - not calorie-free" <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  "111 - wasteful/ too much packaging" <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  "052 - high in carbohydrates" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "067 - high in sugar" <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  "131 - not good for breakfast/ morning" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "068 - dislike/ contains high fructose corn syrup" <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  "125 - not good for a snack" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "123 - not good for kids" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "017 - dislike taste of/ contains center/ filling/ stuffing (unspecified)" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "102 - messy" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "106 - other ease of packaging comments;nosort" <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
)
```

Comment: have you tried using spread and gather in r

Comment: Yes, thought of that but clueless...

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Required_ouput <- gather(Raw_data,key,val,-Verbatim) %>% select(-key) %>%
                  table() %>% as.data.frame.matrix() %>% select(-1)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this helps to reduce the processing time, such that others can learn from your code?

Comment: Can we do it without table() function because it shows the collective count for respective rows instead is there a solution wherin it only shows the count as 0/1 and make a duplcate rows incase there are 2 similar comments?